# How popular is PHP Zip Extension?

Tags: php, hosting, php-extension, php-ziparchive

How popular is PHP [ZIP extension](http://ua.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) by hosting providers? Can I use it as default archive software for my WordPress plugin or should I take a look at another lib?

Comment: If this doesn't work, you could always have a fallback to zip/bz2/tar accessed via `system()` calls. If several fallbacks don't work, then affected users should change their hosting provider :)

Comment: Most shared hosting providers include this, so its a good starting point, but don't assume: check and have a fallback.  I fundamentally disagree with the concept "affected users should change their hosting provider":  better "affected users will fail back to no compression" or whatever.

Comment: @TerryE: yes, if that's possible. Perhaps there are PHP compression libraries in PEAR or something? - they'd be slow but at least they'd work. But some LAMP/cPanel hosting is configured in such as way as to be nearly unusable, and always catering for such hosting encourages its proliferation - and in so doing the developer makes a rod for his/her own back :)

Comment: Have a look at what in included in the debian core distro.  Every shared hosting provider that I've come across offers **zip** and **zlib** support at a minimum.  Clearly VM owners can load what they want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably easiest if you test for the existence of the extension in your scripts, and use your alternative if Ziparchive doesn't exist. I use a wrapper class that checks whether the class is present, and switches to using pclzip (which is included in my library distribution) if not... but all the calls are made to the wrapper to pass on to ZipArchive or PCLZip as appropriate.